# Python IDLE right-to-left language support

Tags: python-3.x, python-idle, right-to-left, ubuntu-14.04

I have recently started to use python 3.4 on Ubuntu and installed python 3.4 IDLE.
I have used the IDLE before on Windows and it works fine and correctly displays Farsi or Arabic which are written right-to-left.
However, on Ubuntu when I try to print a Farsi word on python IDLE it does not show the word correctly. 
Here is an example, the correct rendering of word is:

مجلس

but on IDLE I see

س ل ج  م

Is this something related to Ubuntu or IDLE and how can I fix it?

Comment: I am both surprised and pleased that bidi works on Windows. When I put the cursor in the middle of the work, the parts before and after the cursor are separately reversed.  The fact that the characters are visible in Idle, but typically not in console Python or indeed, other editors, is due to tcl/tk handing the full BMP subset of unicode instead of being limited to a codepage.

Answer (score 0):

```
# -*- coding: utf8 -*-
print(u"مجلس")
```

You need to add a header for utf8 on top to add support for those characters.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I do have `# -*- coding: utf8 -*-` header, it works on windows but not Ubuntu.

Comment: In Python 3, utf-8 is the default in the absence of an encoding line.

Comment: And the u prefix on the string is meaningless.  It is only allowed to make it easier to write code that will also run on 2.7.

Comment: My guess now is that this is an issue with tcl/tk on Ubuntu, or maybe linux in general.